# Can not reinstall Windows7 (using Boot camp) after i've removed Bootcamp partition via Disk Utility

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition

I've removed `Windows` partition (might be label as `Bootcamp`) using `Disk Utility`. and after that i found that i made some mistake because in actually i should remove it via `Bootcamp Assistant`. What's wrong with me now?

[image]

I couldn't find installation menu on `Bootcamp` there's only remove menu. In my understanding i think because `Bootcamp` now still remember the starting file or boot file of `Windows`.

Additional Information from `diskutil list` command:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            300.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data WINDOWS_HD              199.2 GB   disk0s4
```

**NOTE** `WINDOWS_HD` i just create it from `Disk Utility` program there is nothing inside just blank space no Windows.

Comment: Please start `Terminal.app` enter `diskutil list` (followed by return key), copy the output and add it to your question.

Comment: @klanomath Information is update sir.

Comment: Then just remove Windows 7 with the Bootcamp Assistant. Check back with `diskutil list` if "Macintosh HD" has been extended to full size. Then start the `Bootcamp Assistant` again and install Windows 7

Comment: No, @klanomath that should not work because what it recommend me to remove is my `OS X` partition not `Windows` only one choice it give me.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of that choice

Answer (score 1):

OK, now i got my installation screen back

[image]

How could i solve this problem?

I just remove a blank NTFS partition (label as `WINDOWS_HD`) and leave it be a free space. That's all.